# Understanding move semantics for std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to understand move semantics, so I did the following test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void tryToMove(array<double,3> && v) {
    array<double,3> v_ = std::move(v);
    std::cout << v_[0] << "  " << v_[1] << "  " << v_[2] <<'\n';
}

int main () {
    array<double,3> v{1,2,3};

    tryToMove(std::move(v));
    std::cout << v[0] << "  " << v[1] << "  " << v[2] <<'\n';
}
```

I was expecting a sementation fault in the `std::cout` of the main since v_ is supposed to be moved in `tryToMove`. However, the output is:

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

What is exactly happening here?

Thank you!

Comment: What does move semantics have to do with a segmentation fault? Do you expect undefined behavior? If so, undefined behavior isn't code for "will always crash".

Comment: When you call `std::move` on some object you have to assume that it's been successfully moved from. The standard says the object is in a valid but unspecified state after a move, so the values in the array aren't deterministic. The move-constructor for `std::array` is implicit though so it will simply copy the underlying array and nothing more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I was expecting a sementation fault

First of all, most ways to get a segfault are as a result of undefined behaviour, in which case **anything** can happen and you probably shouldn't be **expecting** anything specific.

> since `v_` is supposed to be moved

A `std::array` contains its elements embedded directly inside it (not on the heap, referred to by a pointer, like a `std::vector` does) so you can't move its contents anywhere. They will always be inside it.

So all you've done is initialize a new array from the old one, you haven't moved anything. The elements of the new array will be initialized by rvalue doubles, but that doesn't move anything either, because you can't "move" a double (it has no externally-allocated data to transfer either). So it's just a copy of each element.

Comment: These subtle C++ things kill me. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JaviV If you're trying to learn I would not dismiss it as subtle.

Comment: Of course I am trying to learn, but the weird thing is that I do not consider myself a beginner :)

Comment: @JaviV, Some classes make guarantees for moved-from objects, but in general, you can't do anything with one except assign to it or destroy it. That's a pretty good rule of thumb.

Comment: @chris, I disagree with that rule of thumb, it's far more conservative than necessary.

Comment: I'm with chris on this one. Sometimes conservatism is rewarding. Being only as conservative as is "necessary" seems like a strange way to program.

Comment: If I have a moved-from `std::vector` nothing's going to stop me calling `clear()` and reusing it, for example. The rule of thumb is "don't do anything that has preconditions, without checking the preconditions". That's not much more difficult to learn that "nothing except assign and destroy".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you *expected* a segmentation fault just because you accessed memory that is no longer yours.

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.

In this instance, the state of `v` is unspecified, so your accesses to three elements of it may be valid or may not be. When they are valid (which they probably are because the underlying data is likely to be copied in this case) you're fine; when they are invalid, you cannot simply assume that the result will be a segmentation fault. A few things have to come together for the OS to raise a segmentation fault: it's not a magic bullet for detecting bugs.

Comment: But the memory is "yours".

Comment: @juanchopanza: That is _completely_ unspecified (within the abstraction)

Comment: Isn't move of an `int` well specified? And given the semantics of an array's move constructor, and the invariant that `a.size() == N` for `a` of type `array<T, N>`, it doesn't seem completely unspecified to me.

Comment: Yeah, the blanket "valid but unspecified state" wording says "Unless otherwise specified" (which is implicit in the whole standard anyway) and the precise specification of `std::array` counts as "otherwise specified" in my book.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Still, I'm more interested in helping the OP unlearn misconceptions about UB, than about arguing over the extent to which we ought to treat practical deductions as standard mandates. :)

Comment: It's very relevant, as saying "the memory is no longer yours" implies you can't write new values into the moved-from array then keep using it....

Comment: @TonyD: You misread it. That paragraph relates to the OP's false understanding of segmentation faults, not to `std::array`. Did you read the rest of the answer?

Comment: To those saying "of course it is ok to read the entries", the values of the `double` could include a trap representation under the standard, and `move`ing from them could set the `double` to said trap representation (heck, if it was there, doing so in debug would be awesome).  Reading could then do anything (like seg fault, or nasal demons).  Writing would remain valid, `arr.size() == N`, etc.

Comment: @Yakk How could it? move or not, the assignment of a `double` is done using the built-in assignment operator, whose behavior is fully defined and does not include "make the rhs a trap".

Comment: @t.c. I thought `double` was heavily underspecified in the standard.  Has that changed?

Comment: @Yakk The issue is not `double`. It's the built-in `=`, which doesn't modify its right operand.

Comment: @T.C. It is specified precisely nowhere that moving an `std::array` performs `=` from each source element and nothing else.

Comment: 12.8/15: _"if the member is an array, each element is direct-initialized with the corresponding subobject of x;"_ is all we know

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, and direct-initializing a `double` from a `double` of whatever value category is fully specified in [dcl.init]/p17.8. Still nothing about modifying the source.

Comment: @T.C. Right. I'm just baffled by your comment about `=`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the spec clearly says that "An instance of `array<T, N>` stores `N` elements of type `T`, so that `size() ==
N` is an invariant.", and so even moving from it doesn't change that.

Comment: @AntonSavin Please refer to every single prior comment on this thread